# Текст по умолчанию в Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как в поле краткое описание и описание товара разместить текст по умолчанию?

К примеру когда пользователь переходит на страницу добавления товара, поля "описание" и "краткое описание" уже заполнены каким-то произвольным текстом
[image: краткое описание например]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как в поле краткое описание и описание товара разместить текст по
> умолчанию?

Можно [создать плагин](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) со следующим содержанием:

```
function sv_default_post_content($content) {
    global $post;
    if (function_exists('get_current_screen') && get_current_screen()->post_type =='product' ){
     $content = 'Текст по умолчанию в описании товара';
    }
     return $content;
}
add_filter('default_content', 'sv_default_post_content');

function sv_default_post_excerpt($excerpt) {
    global $post;
    if (function_exists('get_current_screen') && get_current_screen()->post_type =='product' ){
     $excerpt = 'Текст по умолчанию в кратком описании товара';
    }
     return $excerpt;
}
add_filter('default_excerpt', 'sv_default_post_excerpt');
```

Где заменить тексты на нужные.

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли)

Comment: Предложено решение - вариант, согласен, но появляется вопрос, что туда человек будет пихать и зачем? :) Типа: Описание заполнять тута, Детальное описание заполнять здеся? Может проще тупым доступ к админке не давать или создать инструкцию? Хотя, что пиши, что не пиши, если обезьяне дать гранату, хоть напиши на ней, не срывать чеку, всё одно сделает это.

Comment: @Sergio ну например описания могут иметь "многобукв", но при этом не отличаться  или отличаться не на много. Или например могут быть какие-то стандартные тексты (например характеристики, способы использования, и тп.), которые потом дополняются. Просто чтобы не копипастить одно и тоже. Да, такой подход не очень хороший с т.з. SEO, но для начинающих ИМов вполне себе решение.

Comment: @SeVlad У меня на сайте много текстов ОЧЕНЬ похожих в описании товаров, но это можно отследить только выгрузив в эксель и визуально понять, что описание отличается одним, двумя словами. Если честно, то я не представляю, как можно провести сравнительный анализ на лету, это потребует большой нагрузки и сомневаюсь, что без лютых тормозов, это реализуемо. Да, если по крону запускать аналитический скрипт, потом выдавать в начале описания предупреждение о схожести, да ещё оповещать людей на почту, что те или иные товары/статьи надо переписать... Людей и рук не хватает (((

Comment: @SeVlad если рассмотреть обратную ситуацию, то что можно автоматом залить в описание товара? То же, что есть в характеристиках/свойствах... сомнительно, поскольку у нас СЕОшник предлагает такие тексты, что в здравом уме и не догадаешься, что народ так ищет или сопоставляет одно с другим...

Comment: @Sergio, ты сильно заморочился и совсем не о том думаешь. Ни тебе ни мне это не надо (я из файла всё загружаю), а людям вот понадобилось. Решение простое и не опасное.